# Using unowned reference in a closure

Tags: swift, closures

The The Swift Programming Language documentation states:

> Define a capture in a closure as an unowned reference when the closure and the instance it captures will always refer to each other, and will always be deallocated at the same time.

So the only scenario that come to my mind is this one:

```
class ClassWithClosure {
  lazy var someClosure: () -> String = {
    [unowned self] in
    self.myMethod()
  }

  func myMethod(){

  }
}
```

Are there more scenarios where the closure and the instance will be deallocated at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime ClassWithClosure instance's reference count hits 0, the instance will be deallocated. Since the instance is getting deallocated, its properties would be deallocated as well. So anytime ClassWithClosure instance is deallocated, the closure would be deallocated as well. You can't tell the same for other way around. What I mean is if you set someClosure to nil, then it won't cause deallocation of the ClassWithClosure instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late. Just now looking into these matters for myself. How about this?

```
protocol Notifier {
    typealias Client = (Data) -> Void
    typealias Token = Any

    func register(client: Client) -> Token

    // The previously registered Consumer is discarded
    func deregister(token: Token)
}

class Registrant {
    private let name: String
    private let notifier: Notifier
    private var token: Notifier.Token? = nil

    init(name: String, notifier: Notifier) {
        self.name = name
        self.notifier = notifier

        token = notifier.register { [unowned self] (data: Data) in
            print("\(self.name) has been notified: \(data)")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        if let token = token {
            notifier.deregister(token: token)
        }
    }
}
```